# Android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class - Intent in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

The application is causing an error in run time when I am using the application, it is an error in the intent but there is no error in the code from what I can see, it says:

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class .... have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

However it does not need to be stated in the manifest as it is a fragment, I have stated the Activity in the manifest which it inflates from.

```
        @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {   //I
    Intent i = new Intent(ViewAllRecipe.this.getActivity(), EditRecipesFragment.class);
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String RecId = map.get(Config.TAG_ID).toString();
    i.putExtra(Config.REC_ID, RecId);
    getActivity().startActivity(i);
}
```

The error is coming from the:

```
    getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

The Activity which it is being inflated from is, also other fragments are working fine only this one;

```
       <activity
        android:name=".NavigationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Thank you!

Comment: A fragment cannot be passed as an activity. You need a fragmentmanager to add fragments to an activity that you have inflated.

Comment: we can however use getActivity() to basically parse it as an activity, can we not?

Comment: If you need a fragment to use as an activity, why don t you just use an activity? fragments are used for integration with bigger screens.

Comment: `getActivity()` returns the `Activity` the `Fragment` is attached to @ImtananRaja

Answer (score 1):

You can call one Activity from a different Activity/Fragment using this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourNewActivity.class);
```

the above constructor will take up two parameters explained below.

1). A `Context` as its first parameter (this is used because the `Activity` class is a subclass of `Context`)

2). The `Class` of the app component to which the system should deliver the `Intent` (in this case, the activity that should be started)

But in your case, second parameter is a `Fragment`, which doesn't rely to the above syntax and the reason why you are getting `ActivityNotFoundException` is because in this line

```
Intent i = new Intent(ViewAllRecipe.this.getActivity(), EditRecipesFragment.class);
```

JVM is expecting second parameter to be an `Activity` Class and when it didn't find any such class in the `manifest`, it throws the `ActivityNotFoundException`.

For calling `Fragment` from an `Activity`, you have to make use of [FragmentTransactions](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Comment: The stated above code is also a Fragment, essentially it is meant to be calling a fragment from a fragment

Comment: you can call an Activity from a fragment using Intent but not vice versa. Also if you case is Fragment to Fragment , so you need to study about FragmentTransactions

Answer (score 0):

This line looks like a mistake to me:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ViewAllRecipe.this.getActivity(), EditRecipesFragment.class);
```

You can't use startActivity against a Fragment class.  startActivity only works with Activity subclasses that are registered in the manifest.

If you have a fragment that you want to show *within* an activity, you need to locate a container view for that activity and use a FragmentTransaction via the FragmentManager for the activity to arrange for the fragment to be made visible.